# MySQL: Show row number in SELECT query output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySQL database. I want to display the item number (not the primary key) and then a row number.

```
item_num, row_number
1, 1
12, 2
1234, 3
15, 4
29, 5
```

Here is my query:

```
select item_num, row_number() over(partition by item_num) from items;
```

My output is this:

```
item_num, row_number
1, 1
12, 1
1234, 1
15, 1
29, 1
```

How can I fix this issue and show the correct row number for each item?

Comment: you have 1 unique value per partition, so naturally you have 1 per row. Is `id` a string or integer? Remove the partition and add an *order by*

Comment: @Stu, id is a integer value

Comment: So why does 1234 come after 12 and before 15?

Comment: @Stu, they are just values, it is not a primary key in my table. let me change the column name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

The following query should create the behaviour you want:

```
SELECT item_num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() FROM items;
```

### Explanation

The `ROW_NUMBER()` formula sequentially numbers the rows of each partition which is passed into it. It begins again at 1 for each partition, independently. Therefore, attempting to partition the database by item_num before using `ROW_NUMBER()` will result in each unique item_num being assigned a row number of 1.

Instead, use a blank `OVER()` clause. There's no need to partition the database or order it in any specific way, since you simply want to apply `ROW_NUMBER()` based on the order already present in the database.

Comment: you can just do `OVER ()`; no need for a dummy ORDER BY.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88a4efa52852a4ed80b5c938b36a9796

Comment: @ysth Although I don't have the opportunity to test it right now, my understanding is that `ROW_NUMBER()` requires the associated `OVER()` to have either an `ORDER BY` or `PARTITION BY` clause, and will throw an error if neither are present. Is this not the case?

Comment: that is not the case; see the fiddle I linked.  the doc says "ORDER BY affects the order in which rows are numbered. Without ORDER BY, row numbering is nondeterministic."  so you could do a query twice and get different orders between them, and there's not necessarily any relation between the order ROW_NUMBER returns and the order the query actually returns (though in practice it would surprise me if they differed).  But that's all just as true for your `ORDER BY NULL`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't even notice your link before now. I'll update my answer to reflect this.